# Variable not incrementing in destructor call?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class constructor {
public:
    static int c, d;

    constructor() {
        c++;
    }
    ~constructor() {
        d++;
    }
};

int constructor::c, constructor::d;

int main() {
    constructor c;
    cout<<constructor::c<<" "<<constructor::d;
    return 0;
}
```

`Output: 1 0`

If I make an explicit call to destructor, then, the output is, `1 1`

I would like to know, why isn't `d` incrementing when destructor is called implicitly?

Comment: Four virtually identical answers and counting … 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The destructor is not being called in your example because the object is still available in the current scope. There are different ways of destroying the object in the current scope, here is a quick list:

### Create a block

The object will be destroyed at the end of the block.

```
{
    constructor c;
}
cout << constructor::c << " " << constructor::d;
```

### Reset a Unique Pointer

We could create a unique pointer and call the `reset()` method to release it.

```
auto uniquePtr = std::make_unique<constructor>();
uniquePtr.reset();
cout << constructor::c << " " << constructor::d;
```

### Reset a Shared Pointer

We could also create a shared pointer and `reset()` it.

```
auto sharedPtr = std::make_shared<constructor>();
sharedPtr.reset();
cout << constructor::c << " " << constructor::d;
```

### Call the destructor directly

Still in the list of possibilities, C++ allows you to call a destructor directly.

```
constructor c;
c.~constructor();
cout << constructor::c << " " << constructor::d;
```

Answer (score 3):

You're printing before the destructor of `c` is called - it will be called at the end of the scope. Adding a new block produces your expected output:

```
int main() {
    {
        constructor c;
    }
    cout<<constructor::c<<" "<<constructor::d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know, why isn't d incrementing when destructor is called implicitly?

It is, but by the time you output `constructor::d`, it *hasn’t* been called yet. Change the code to

```
{
    constructor c;
}
cout<<constructor::c<<" "<<constructor::d;
```

To see the destructor call: this code constructs `c` in a smaller scope, and destructs it at the end of the smaller scope (here: at the `}`).

Answer (score 1):

The life-time of the variable `c` haven't ended yet when you try to print the `d` member. The variable is still alive and in scope.

If you try e.g.

```
int main()
{
    // Add a new nested scope
    {
        constructor c;  // Construct object in nested scope
    }
    // Nested scope ended, so the life-time of c have ended and it has been destructed

    cout<<constructor::c<<" "<<constructor::d;
}
```

Then the destructor counter should have been increased.

Comment: does that mean, the destructor is called after scope of `c` is ended?

Comment: @ArihantBedagkar First of all, scope and life-time are not related. The life-time of an object could be longer than the scope in which it was created (thing for example `new`). On the other hand, for "local" variables (like `c`) then their life-time ends with the end of the scope they were created in. When the life-time of an object ends, the object is destructed and that of course means the destructor will be called.